# How to like s3 bucket with subdomain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I have ex: `mydomain.com` I need to make my file manager bucket link my domain with `files.mydomain.com/` What I did

1. create a bucket `files.mydomain.co` and make it public:

[image]

the bucket URL is: `https://s3.me-south-1.amazonaws.com/files.mydomainn.co/contracts/mobile-82-qrcode.svg`

Then I went to Route53 & put the URL of the bucket in `CHNAME` of a subdomain:

[image]

The subdomain does not work!

Am I missing something!?

======================**UPDATE** =========================

I create Clouldfront like this

[image]
[image]
[image]

Then I went to `Route53` and create a new record:

[image]

After minutes when I visit my subdomain I got a weird error:

[image]

Comment: Setting up a CNAME to point to a URL won't work.  Have you tried following the [directions from AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A CNAME record is for the host only.  So, for example, you can create a CNAME record from `files.example.com` to `s3.me-south-1.amazonaws.com` but not including both the protocol and sub-directory you show.

Additionally, you'll have SSL certificate issues doing this as the certificate is not for your domain.

Your best bet would be to use [CloudFront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Introduction.html) to be in front of your S3 bucket.  You'll be able to create a SSL certificate that matches your domain name and use the hostname you'd like.  It's not free but it's very affordable.

Comment: Hi sir can you please check my question again I updated it with `CloudFront` steps